# EF Core (in-memory database) - 'The instance of entity type X cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xunit

I am using xunit with an Entity Framework in-memory database. For each test a new instance of my in memory database is created and then disposed.

I get the following error when running more than 1 tests.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Account_Master' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{NUMBER_INT: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

From what I can see the issue arises when I try and populate my in-memory database with fake test data. On the first test, I add an dummy account, and a dummy scope (these are referenced by foreign key). This works fine.

However on the next test, when I add the dummy scope, it automatically adds the dummy account (even though it should not know about it yet).

I have an example code project here
https://github.com/welcometochristown/efCoreErrorTest

I have two database contexts in this project

```
FakeAccountContext
FakeSmtrSimpleContext
```

For some reason the `FakeAccountContext` works, but the `FakeSmtrSimpleContext` doesn't (even though they are nearly identical).

To reproduce error

```
Build project
Open the test explorer
Expand tests
Right click "SmtrSimpleTest" -> Run (error!)
Right click "AccountTest" -> Run (works!)
```

Using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory (3.1.27)

Comment: >For each test a new instance of my in memory database is created and then disposed.    You mean for each test class, not for each test (each [Fact]) right?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins No, for each individual test a new instance is created and disposed. Each with a unique name.

Comment: But the test class is created only once, then all its tests are run. In your example code you have two tests in the class, and the AccountDbContext member is final, so the same one will be used for each of the tests in the class.

Comment: This is not the case with xunit. https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context. "xUnit.net creates a new instance of the test class for every test that is run". Also, even if this was the case both test classes would fail, not just one.

Comment: I just learned something, tested and confirmed just to be sure. Most of my work is with shared context, I had simply assumed the test class was persisted as well.

Comment: I built your project and the problem is reproduced on my system as well. Still stumped on why.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins I think the root cause is because the entities I am adding to the context are static. My best guess is some in-memory reference must persist between the static entity and each in-memory database that is initialized.

Comment: That was also the angle I would investigate.

Comment: btw next time don't forget the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hypothesis about the static properties maintaining references to the entities between tests is correct.

In the debugger, on the second test, in a breakpoint *before* the `Account_Master.Add()`, we can see that the static `SmtrSimpleDummyAccount` (an  `Account_Master`) of the previous test still exists:

[image: Debugger display showing Account_Master exists before Add]

I changed the static properties to methods that return a new object, then forget it instead of maintaining a static reference to it:

```
 public static class FakeAccount
    {
        public static Account DummyAccount()
        {
            return new Account
            {
                NUMBER_INT = 1,
                SCOPE_CHR = FakeAccountScope.Public().SCOPE_CHR
            };
        }


        public static Account_Master SmtrSimpleDummyAccount()
        {
            return new Account_Master
            {
                NUMBER_INT = 1,
                SCOPE_CHR = "Public",
            };
        }
    }
```

and

```
public static class FakeAccountScope
    {
        public static AccountScope Private()
        {
            return new AccountScope
            {
                SCOPE_CHR = nameof(Private)
            };
        }

        public static AccountScope Public()
        {
            return new AccountScope
            {
                SCOPE_CHR = nameof(Public)
            };
        }

        public static X_Account_Scope SmtrSimplePublic()
        {
            return new X_Account_Scope
            {
                SCOPE_CHR = nameof(Public)
            };
        }

        public static X_Account_Scope SmtrSimplePrivate()
        {
            return new X_Account_Scope
            {
                SCOPE_CHR = nameof(Private)
            };
        }

    }
```

And now all the tests pass:

[image: Tests pass]

Possibly also relevant for your `FakeAccount.SmtrSimpleDummyAccount`: [How to create a static lambda for use with expression building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217853/how-to-create-a-static-lambda-for-use-with-expression-building)

Comment: This is the same result I got when making the entities non-static, I guess it is just an issue with entity framework in-memory databases. Thanks for the help, this one was definitely blowing my brain for a while.