# Lambda without nonlocal dependencies is not static

Tags: c#, .net, static, delegates, visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, .NET 4.6, and I wrote some code that relies on Delegates being static. I ran the exact code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603965/why-do-some-c-sharp-lambda-expressions-compile-to-static-methods) question, but I get "false":

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string> actionMethod = s => { Console.WriteLine("My Name is " + s); };

    // Always false
    Console.WriteLine(actionMethod.Method.IsStatic);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Is this a bug? Or does C# not guarantee that lambdas without nonlocal dependencies are made static?

Is there a workaround to determine if a lambda/delegate has nonlocal dependencies? My goal is to know if a lambda caught it's enclosing variables / uses a closure.

Comment: See [Delegate caching behavior changes in Roslyn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897647/delegate-caching-behavior-changes-in-roslyn) for an explanation as to why this change was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or does C# not guarantee that lambdas without nonlocal dependencies are made static?

It makes no such guarantee.  That was an implementation detail of some versions of the compiler; one that it has no obligation to continue with going forward.  As you have seen, they've changed that implementation detail.