# Why do local functions have the "internal" access modifier?

Tags: c#

Why does the Roslyn compiler generate local functions with the `internal` access modifier (in IL, `assembly`) instead of `private`?

```cs
    private void M()
    {
        bool f = true;
        bool x1() => f;
        static bool x2() => true;
    }
```

```
    .method assembly hidebysig static
        bool '<M>g__x1|0_0' (
            valuetype C/'<>c__DisplayClass0_0'& ''
        ) cil managed { ... }

    .method assembly hidebysig static
        bool '<M>g__x2|0_1' () cil managed { ... }
```

[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYAEBhHAbwFgAoHCnABwCcoA3CBAUxwwBYcBZACgEoylIoKGVgAe3EocAMxwBeHAhoBXZgG4RonBKk4AHgEZ+CgHyzN5bW0MA2HZOn6sJ+eeVrLQgL5acAegAqCj9acRYAYxYAEzZOKn5CXysKWBYaGAhpDhwoROShMMiY3Jh0zOz4vL4kv38g/zJvIA)

Docs say that it should be private: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions

> Local functions are private methods of a type that are nested in another member.

> Because all local functions are private, including an access modifier, such as the private keyword, generates compiler error CS0106

Comment: Side note: the spec you linked has no relation to the generated code - the spec is about adding access modifier *in the C# code* while what you are showing is decompiled code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in first line it says `Local functions are private methods of a type that are nested in another member.`. And private method of a type means it should be private. It's not a normative document, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: possibly an ignorant question: does it matter in practice? I think you can't access the local function outside of it's scope anyway.

Comment: @bolov 1. Semantics 2. Reflection 3. MSIL is one of .NET languages that can name those functions

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35839913/87698 (this is about the IL access modifier of lambda expressions). Apparently, the compiler teams sees access modifiers for auto-generated, non-user-callable methods as an undocumented implementation detail. Your question is a very good and interesting one, though, I'd be curious to learn more about the design rationale behind this decision.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Referring to MSIL/CIL as though it were a CLS language (like C# and VB.NET) is like saying x86 machine code is a high-level programming language.

Comment: Anyway, I _speculate_ that the function is `internal` so that the compiler can de-dupe the function's code in-case it sees the same function logic used elsewhere in the program (without needing to relocate it into another type). If it were `private` then the CLI's program-loader would complain about the program violating access-modifier rules.

Comment: The behavior is documented in a unit-test here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/bc3212cc70a2aa69648b80329b42e939831ed379/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Emit/CodeGen/CodeGenClosureLambdaTests.cs 

Look for `TestClosureMethodAccessibility()`: - however it doesn't explain **why** the compiler does it.

Comment: The actual spec on local functions is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/local-functions). Note that it still says "TODO: WRITE SPEC" (in big capitals) and includes no details on the accessibility. Later versions of the spec refine what you can do with local functions, but do not improve on this point at all. C# is long, long overdue for a spec that is not "draft", even if building new features is a lot sexier than rolling them up into one formal spec, and even if the (informal) language description usually does a decent job.

Comment: @Dai can copy class definition and just change it's name. No code reused

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic I don't understand what you're referring to

Comment: @Dai https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoTyAEBhHAb0x1JwAcAnKANwgBcBTHBAFhwFkAKAShLOIYywnMAD2YgDY4AZjgC8OepQCujANz8ROWPRxiFOAByah20ROkAPFLwUA+WafMsUANgtScVpHfmPlNWdzBABWAB5dABodGHpHKwBmQy4rHgciUgQAdhwABnUcAF9g0iLMcoxcPCQiLQpqOiYWdm4+M1JBF3EvOUVAjXrhXX1DEyGyHutbdP8nCaz3T2tfWYDVQY6RMMi4mN0E5MVUtcyWXILi0uKKoA===

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic _"2. Reflection"_ Reflection just circumvents the whole type and access safety features anyway, so it's a bit of an irrelevant case to point out.

Comment: @Flater It modifies non-private interface of the class, so it can interference with various legal use of reflection like RPC (remoting), and with `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` it becomes _<<public>>_ interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like code reuse artifact.
Roslyn probably uses same code to handle local functions and lambdas, but injects method definitions in different classes.

In case of lambda it injects lambda body to generated closure (`DisplayClass`) class and it should be internal to be referenced from calling function.