# Why instantiating a new int changes the output of this code?

Tags: c#

The code below returns the following output:

```
Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(5,5,"sema_1");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
    {
        sema.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(" = " + i);
        sema.Release();
    });
}
```

[image]

And just by adding the int j = i it completely changes the output to what I was expecting, which is the proper response reaching the limit of the Semaphore:

```
Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(5,5,"sema_1");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
    {
        sema.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(" = " + j);
        sema.Release();
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is duplicated

Comment: I don't get the behavior you're describing. Setting int j = i, does not cause i to be captured. Are you sure you aren't printing j?

Comment: it was a typo, I fixed it thanks

Comment: Yeah then it's a duplicate.... also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264289/captured-closure-loop-variable-in-c-sharp-5-0

Comment: Also see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603965/why-do-some-c-sharp-lambda-expressions-compile-to-static-methods?rq=1, which shows how lambdas work.